# A button above a webview in a PopupWindow responds for onClick after 2 times

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have a a WebView and a Button above the top-right corner of it 
my problem is that when I first tap on the button it doesn't work, the 2nd tap (click) works fine.

Its xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/popup3"    
        >
    <WebView
        xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/webviewActionView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/popup_closer"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/close_popup"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text=" " />     
</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like the following: [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0KQk.png)

**Now when I place the ButtonView before the LinearLayout in the code it works from the First click (tap)**

But it looks like this: [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDUvj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Remove or set to false.

Comment: @Shehabix: i am also  have the same problem to show the popup in webview  how do you did the popup window in webview could you share your sample

Comment: @Mr.Cool in your popup window set popupWin.setContentView(webviewReference);

Comment: @Shehabix:do have any sample refference for that

Comment: @Shehabix i have the problem to load the web view inside the popup,for your refference see this http://pastebin.com/31jrJHYe ,inthis i got the popup window but the web page is not displayed